# Unable to do anything on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, uefi, dualboot

My PC have a dual boot Windows 10/ Fedora 33 at the beginning my windows worked perfectly but i don't know why (i don't know if it's an update, an app or a driver that caused all my BSOD), now i can't do anything on windows 10 because i have too much BSOD for some reason so i tried to reset windows 10 (supress all or not), reinstall windows 10 with a bootable USB but nothing works because of blue screens, i'm stuck here so i made this public question, if possible i want to keep data on fedora (i need it for school), i don't have any kind of restore point for windows 10.

Feel free ask me more details then i’ll edit my question.

I’m afraid to broke my PC so if someone have a solution and have time to do screenshare or something like that please contact me on discord ChaiPo#4301.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Linux works well, i didn’t change my windows partition with linux,i can’t even log on windows beacuse of BSODs.

UPDATE 2: I tried to delete all my partitions to have a blank PC without any OS thanks to a linux live usb (who works without any problems) but my windows usb still shows me BSODs so i tried to use my windows usb on an other PC and there was no BSODs.

Non-exhaustive list of BSODs i got:

- IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
- ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION

Comment: Does Linux work well? Have you modified the Windows partition from Linux? Can you boot Windows, and when exactly occur the BSODs?

Comment: If it works on Linux, save all your data, make a disk image to another device, then remove all partitions using Linux on USB, reinstall a *valid* Windows ISO, reinstall Linux, and then restore the Linux partition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot login, you can't do much to fix Windows from inside
Windows.

I suggest to create a Windows boot media and do the
re-installation of Windows. When the installation asks where to
install, specify the partition where Windows is installed.
The installation should detect the existing installation
and just do the same operation as you would get from a
Repair Install with an in-place upgrade

If this will undo Grub and set the boot to Windows only,
you may restore Grub by using the
[Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Take good backups of your data for both Windows and Linux.
You may use Linux to copy the files from Windows.

Comment: I already tried but even on the bootable usb there are crashes so i can’t install or repair that’s why i posted on superuser.

Comment: I would think then that you have a hardware problem, or that the boot media is bad.

Comment: An hardware problem can make me crash on windows and not on fedora ?

Comment: @ChaiPo Yes - they use two completely different kernels, drivers, etc. Run BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics [long test] _(will take several hours)_

Comment: Ok i searched how to do it but nothing work, i have a Lenovo IdeaPad S340 so i tried to tap on F10 and F12 but there is no diagnostic menu.

Comment: Seems like your model doesn't have it. Try perhaps memtest86.

Comment: No errors from memtest86

Comment: That's a good indication, if you have let it run for several passes, the more the better, but at minimum 2.

Comment: I let it run 4 passes, i’ll try 10 passes

Comment: 8 passes are said to be conclusive enough.

Comment: 4 is the max value for free version so i ran another test and no errors again

Comment: Memtest tests pretty well everything connected to memory and somewhat the CPU. Try maybe to re-download the Windows ISO.

Comment: I already try to make a windows usb with windows media tool and another with rufus and it doesn’t change anything

Comment: Something seems to have happened to your computer, detected only by Windows. I can't say what. It might need an intervention by a professional.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help